# Why isn't this compiling?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the below code does not build:

```
bool AguiRectangle::pointInside(const AguiPoint &p )
{
    if(p.getX() < x) return false;
    if(p.getY() < y) return false;
    if(p.getX() >= x + width) return false;
    if(p.getY() >= y + height) return false;
    return true;

}
```

I get this:

```
Error   1   error C2662: 'AguiPoint::getX' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const AguiPoint' to 'AguiPoint &'  c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\agui\alleg_5\agui\aguibasetypes.cpp 259
Error   3   error C2662: 'AguiPoint::getX' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const AguiPoint' to 'AguiPoint &'  c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\agui\alleg_5\agui\aguibasetypes.cpp 261
Error   2   error C2662: 'AguiPoint::getY' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const AguiPoint' to 'AguiPoint &'  c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\agui\alleg_5\agui\aguibasetypes.cpp 260
Error   4   error C2662: 'AguiPoint::getY' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const AguiPoint' to 'AguiPoint &'  c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\agui\alleg_5\agui\aguibasetypes.cpp 262
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The functions `AguiPoint::getX()` and `AguiPoint::getY()` need to be defined as `const` member functions or you won't be able to call them on `const AguiPoint`s.

You attempted to call a non-`const` member function on `p`, which is reference to a `const AguiPoint`. Since references are aliases to the original object, calling a non-`const` member function on a `const AguiPoint &` is equivalent to calling a non-`const` member function on a `const AguiPoint`, which is an error.

It's an error because since the method was not declared `const`, there's no guarantee that it won't modify the `const AguiPoint` instance. Without this guarantee, the compiler must assume that it will somehow modify the `const AguiPoint` object, and attempting to modify a `const`ant object is a bad thing, i.e. a violation of *const-correctness*. A compiler that reasonably conforms to the C++ standard must issue a diagnostic in this case.

Assuming that `AguiPoint::getX()` and `AguiPoint::getY()` are just inspector methods of the class, they really should be `const` anyway since they don't modify the data inside `AguiPoint`:

```
class AguiPoint
{
public:
    // Inspector methods - they don't change the data of an AguiPoint.
    int getX() const { /* Implementation */ } // Note const member function
    int getY() const { /* Implementation */ }
};
```

Also, since the function `AguiRectangle::pointInside()` doesn't modify any data members of `AguiRectangle`, you should define `AguiRectangle::pointInside()` as a `const` member function as well:

```
bool AguiRectangle::pointInside(const AguiPoint &p ) const // Note const
{
    /* Implementation */
}
```

Const-correctness is an important and fundamental concept in C++, so be sure to read up on [this FAQ on const-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) and [the Guru of the Week article #6](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm). There's even a pretty good [Wikipedia article on const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness).